# Adding conditional class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well, I'm really noob so I'm asking if it's the correct way or there's a simpler way to do it.

What I want is to add a class to an element depending of a value... so what I do its the next:

HTML:

```
<progress value="{{ luminaria.nivelcargabateria }}"></progress>
```

Directive definition:

```
angular.module('angularJSApp')
  .directive('progress', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'views/progress.html',
      scope: {
        value: '@'
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.barClass = function () {
          return ($scope.value > 66)?'success':($scope.value > 33)?'warning':'danger';
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Directive template:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-{{ barClass() }}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ value }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{ value }}%">
  <span class="sr-only">{{ value }}%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure why you need directive, but do look at ng-class directive in angular.

Answer (score 1):

You could use very handy `ng-class` directive http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass

For example

```
<div ng-class="success: aboutToFinish(), warning: inProgress(), danger: justStarted()"></div>
```

And inside the controller:

```
$scope.aboutToFinish = function() {
  return $scope.value > 66;
}

$scope.inProgress = function() {
  return $scope.value > 33 && $scope.value < 66;
}

$scope.justStarted = function() {
  return !($scope.inProgress() && $scope.finished());
}
```

IMHO this solution would be much more readable, maintainable and you could write a unit test for this piece without any effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is better, but you could use `ng-class` for this as well:

```
angular.module('angularJSApp')
  .directive('progress', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'views/progress.html',
      scope: {
        value: '@'
      }
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:progress-bar-{{ barClass() }}

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" ng-class="{'progress-bar-success': value>66, 'progress-bar-danger': value>33, 'progress-bar-danger': value<=33}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ value }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{ value }}%">
  <span class="sr-only">{{ value }}%</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's quite easy, using `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-class="{'class-a': testCondition, 'class-b': anotherTestCondition}"></div>
```